# Fixed header is transparent?

Tags: html, css

I have a little question. My fixed header is transparent and the content from my Website go above the header if I scroll down. But I would like header to go above the content, can anyone help me?

The Red box should be the Header and the Green box are the Content you can see that the text and the Pictures go over the Header:

My Header.php

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: #F9F6F3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <header id="fh5co-header" role="banner">
    Here are the Header Text and the Logo

  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: i can see `</header>` close tag but where is `<header>` in Header.php

Comment: Sorry i add the line in the example :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting this error - for me, the content is always behind the header in your example.

However, you can make sure to avoid this issue with "z-index", a css tag that decides what is in front of what.

In the example below, I gave your header a z-index of 10, meaning it should be in front of anything that doesn't have a z index, like the content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>TitleT</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />

  <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />

  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="boxed">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="fh5co-page">


      <style>
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        #header {
          background-color: #F9F6F3;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100px;
          z-index: 10;
        }
      </style>
      <div id="header">
        <header id="fh5co-header" role="banner">
          <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle dark"><i></i></a>
            <div id="fh5co-logo">
              <a href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" height="50" width="95" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <nav id="fh5co-main-nav" role="navigation">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="about">sdf</a></li>
                <li class="has-sub">
                  <div class="drop-down-menu">
                    <a href="services.html">dfgdfg</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-wrap">
                      <ul>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">asd</a></li>
                <li class="has-sub">
                  <div class="drop-down-menu">
                    <a href="#">gzu</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-wrap">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="quotation">Ser</a></li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="cta"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="fh5co-intro" class="fh5co-section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center ts-intro">
              <h1>About Us</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm">
            <div class="col-md-8" id="fh5co-content">
              <h2>History</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus possimus, quaerat tenetur quos ad nostrum eaque esse, ex blanditiis deleniti accusantium molestias perferendis odio, iste cum. Hic eius, ullam repellendus. Possimus, ratione?
                Qui, tempora, eveniet! Eveniet facilis nesciunt commodi nostrum!</p>
              <p>Illum provident, rerum hic porro doloremque alias voluptatibus fugit aliquam aspernatur molestiae debitis fuga, expedita vel animi eius, ab natus in enim repellendus harum! Est atque quae aut? Sint quis expedita illo placeat ad saepe hic
                quidem dolore laboriosam? Sapiente.</p>
              <p>Similique sint consequuntur cum ea quia placeat aliquid blanditiis atque, et earum sit sequi. Earum dignissimos omnis, hic atque ducimus quibusdam eos, exercitationem cum ea ipsum, est animi nesciunt. Consequuntur molestias ratione asperiores
                sequi nam minima dignissimos voluptas consequatur nemo.</p>
              <p>Ut sit repellat id dignissimos excepturi recusandae reprehenderit eius, voluptatem et ab quos qui sequi rem sapiente, delectus numquam officiis. Maxime aliquam unde eum quo, sit qui voluptatum odio nam. Iste vitae, sed enim facilis suscipit
                quis obcaecati quas, nobis.</p>
              <p>Cupiditate commodi velit officia quidem dolores incidunt, deserunt nam quaerat aliquam labore iure quam. Exercitationem tempora itaque error odio quasi quas illo consequatur nisi debitis, aliquam magnam voluptas, quia, impedit, architecto
                fugit suscipit officia ullam laudantium sit libero excepturi deserunt.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="fh5co-sidebar">
              <div class="fh5co-service text-left">
                <img src="images/slider_2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-bordered" alt="Free HTML5 Bootstrap Template by FreeHTML5.co">
                <h3>WDesign</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ullam unde, totam harum laboriosam dolores.</p>
                <ul class="ul_style_1">

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <p><img src="images/slider_3.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Bootstrap Template" class="img-responsive img-bordered"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 padded-top">
              <h3>Creative Title Here</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum fuga rerum doloremque dolore, molestias eligendi. Nulla aliquam aut doloribus tenetur repellendus omnis dicta, unde magni.</p>
              <ul class="ul_style_1">
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <footer id="fh5co-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              <div class="fh5co-footer-widget">
                <h3>About Us</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-1 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0">
              <div class="fh5co-footer-widget">
                <h3>Quick Links</h3>
                <ul class="fh5co-footer-link">
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-2 col-sm-12 col-sm-push-0">

              <div class="fh5co-footer-widget">
                <h3>Follow us</h3>
                <ul class="fh5co-social">
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </div>

  <center>
    <center><small class='block'><font size='3'>&copy; 2015-2018 by <a href='https://auszdgfuzasdfg.com'></font></small></center>
  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have add the z-index line and now the Content are under the Header

Comment: Glad I could help :)